# Sending upper case letters to a TextEdit during instrumented tests

Tags: java, android, testing, junit, user-input

I am writing a JUnit test case for my Android app. The test class extends `ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2` and calls `sendKeys()` to emulate user input for `TextEdit` widgets. However, all of the alphabetic keycodes (e.g. `KeyEvent.KEYCODE_G`) only send lower case letters to the `TextEdit`. I tried sending `KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SHIFT_LEFT` before sending an alphabetic keycode, but that didn't seem to work. So how do I simulate the user typing an upper-case letter?

**Edit:**

I can enter upper case letters manually. In fact, the EditText is defined as

```
    <EditText android:id="@id/brand_text"
              android:singleLine="true"
              android:capitalize="words"
              android:hint="@string/brand_hint"
    />
```

The `android:capitalize="words"` attribute forces the onscreen keyboard into uppercase mode in the emulator. (I assume it will do the same on a device but don't have one to test it on.) Since the emulator which comes with the SDK doesn't emulate the hardware keyboard, I have been unable to test how my UI works using hard keys.

I also tried

```
EditText brandText = this.activity.findViewById(R.id.brand_text);
brandText.setText(someString);
```

However, the test failed when I did this. I axed all that code, so I don't have the details here at the moment. I will try to recreate it and edit this question with those details.

Comment: Have you tried sending like sendKeys("A"); instead of KeyEvent.KEYCODE_A)

Comment: @DurairajP Yes, `sendKeys("A")` is equivalent to `sendKeys(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_A)`. [According to the docs `sendKeys(String)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/InstrumentationTestCase.html#sendKeys(int...)): "The sequence of keys is a string containing the key names as specified in KeyEvent, without the KEYCODE_ prefix."

Comment: @Code-Guru : In your question you say you tried `KeyEvent.KEYCODE_LEFT_SHIFT` before the alphabetic code. I'm assuming that's a typo as it should be `KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SHIFT_LEFT`.

Comment: @Squonk Yes, that was a typo...since KEYCODE_LEFT_SHIFT doesn't even exist. (fixed now)

Comment: Shift should work, does the text edit actually allow the input of uppercase letters into it manually? Have you considered using robotium  or just setting the text on the main thread from your test?

Comment: @PaulHarris See my edit to answer parts of your question. I haven't gotten around to checking out robotium yet.

Comment: I think i might know how to solve the issue with the settext at least...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I didn't mention in my OP that I was writing a method to send the characters of a `String` to a text box. I tried using `setText()` as @PaulHarris suggested but couldn't get it to work; my tests still failed some assertions.

After some digging, finally found [`Instrumentation.sendStringSync()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Instrumentation.html#sendStringSync%28java.lang.String%29) which works for my purposes. (You can get an `Instrumentation` object by calling [getInstrumentation()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/InstrumentationTestCase.html#getInstrumentation%28%29) in your test class.)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do something like:

```
EditText brandText = this.activity.findViewById(R.id.brand_text);
brandText.setText(someString);
```

What you actually need to do is:

```
EditText brandText = this.activity.findViewById(R.id.brand_text);
instrumentation.runOnMainSync(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        brandText.setText(someString);
    }
});
```

This is because you need to do any interaction with the gui on the UI Thread (or main thread whatever name you prefer).

A method such as this:

```
public void setText(EditText editText, final String textToSet){
    instrumentation.runOnMainSync(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            brandText.setText(textToSet);
        }
    }); 
}
```

should work for you just fine.

Comment: If/when you have a moment, can you check out my related question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13169235/preferred-way-to-test-edittext-input-in-an-android-junit-class?

Comment: Also, what are the differences between `Instrumentation.runOnMainSync()`, `ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2.runTestOnUiThread()`, and `Activity.runOnUiThread()` (other than the first one runs synchronously)?