# SendKeys Uppercase Letters in android unit test cases

Tags: android, testing, instrumentation, uppercase, sendkeys

I am writing unit test cases for my login application. and I am new in writing test cases.
One of those test cases is I shuold pass username,password to EditText fields and on click of login button it will validate(assertion).
For passing Username/Password I'm using sendKeys(..) api.
I am able to send Lowecase/Uppercase/SpecialCharacters in any device which is below 4.0 version.
But the problem is on/above 4.0 version, I'm not able to send Uppercaseletters.

Here is the sample of my code:

```
sendKeys(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SHIFT_LEFT,KeyEvent.KEYCODE_S, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_A, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_N,................
```

I have tried CAPSLOCK,SHIFT_RIGHT,ALT_RIGHT etc.. nothing is making it Uppercase in 4.0 versions.
I have tried updating the SDK also for new updates. still no use.
Not able to figure out what is the problem.

Please help.

Thanks in advance.
Siri.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sending upper case letters to a TextEdit during instrumented tests](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13280080/sending-upper-case-letters-to-a-textedit-during-instrumented-tests)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an interesting question, but I think someone else has asked this before. The answer was this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13466090/81520 and I am very happy to have found it.